# Off-topic to ask if something is off-topic?

Tags: support, off-topic

Would a question on Meta be off-topic if it's asking if a question would be off-topic on Stack Overflow?

In other words, is "Would this be an off-topic question on Stack Overflow [question here]" off-topic when asked on Meta?

Comment: No... That's part of what the Meta is for... Just be sure you ask about it where you're looking for guidance. Coming here to ask if something is off-topic on SO would be off-topic, though you can ask "where would this question be on-topic".

Comment: Is this off-topic? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298145/would-a-question-about-how-git-works-internally-be-on-topic?cb=1

Comment: No, that example is not off-topic. Why do you ask?

Comment: I mean... it has a ton of upvotes, so clearly it's not off-topic. (yes, I know that upvotes don't always mean it's on-topic but 40+ is a pretty good indicator).

Comment: Lots of questions with lots of upvotes have been closed as "off-topic" - when I find examples I'll show them

Comment: How did you know that this was the right place to ask if this is the right place to ask whether a question is on topic?  This is a paradox.  If this isn't the right place to ask whether something is on topic, then it's off topic for you to ask if asking if something is on topic here.  And if it *is* on topic to ask if it's on topic to ask if something is on topic here then you already have the answer to your question, that it's on topic.

Comment: If you ask yourself this question what will be your answer?

Comment: "Does *whatever* belong on SO?" is a better question for that per-site meta (meta.so) than this overall meta. "Is *whatever* a better fit for [siteA] or [siteB]?" is on topic here on meta for sure.

Comment: You have to go to Meta Meta StackOverflow to ask this.

Comment: @Won't I got a _"This webpage is unavailable"_ error. I'll have to ask about that on Meta Meta Meta StackOverflow :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not off-topic.

This is a normal meta discussion regarding the site's scope, and discussing the scope is one of the most important meta purposes. There's even a meta tag for this reason: [scope](/questions/tagged/scope), which reads:

> Use this tag when examining what is on-topic or off-topic, and why.

<sup>For the sake of irony, I'm very temped to tag your question with the tag I've just mentioned :P</sup>

Answer (score 5):

No. It is **not** off-topic.

If you really don't know, and have read the help center (`/help` of the current sie; eg: [Meta help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help)) and any other related material (ie. on the per-site meta), it is perfectly acceptable to ask on the **meta** *of that site*.

However, *please* do make sure you research *before* posting. Under normal circumstances, the help center's `/on-topic` page will tell you everything you need, however you might need to ask sometimes, and that's OK :)